# Unable to execute the RUN command in Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I am unable to execute the docker RUN command and it shows me everytime the yellow highlighted line, I am basically creating a volume in a container.

I have installed everything as well to run this. Currently running linux container on windows.

**++UPDATE: Here is the docker file**

[image]

**CMD:**

[image: t]

Comment: What is your docker RUN command doing? I'm guessing it's called `dotnet build`, which is a .NET Core SDK command not a .NET Core Runtime command

Comment: I am trying to create a volume for the container

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear enough in my initial comment and that's my fault. When you run the `docker run` command, docker will run the image that you provide and create a container for it. From your screenshot, you are running the `test-image` image and passing it a volume. What is the `RUN` command within `test-image` doing.

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy Can you post your Dockerfile? Or at least the `FROM`, `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` parts?

Comment: I suspect there's a typo in ENTRYPOINT. Change `app/myapp.dll` to `myapp.dll`.

Comment: Also change `COPY ... app/` to `COPY ... /`

Comment: Also, what is the output of `dir app/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish` in cmd?

Comment: I think entry point id defined perfectly because i am using WRKDIR as an /app so all the files from publish go in there and i can access it using app/myapp.dll as usual.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the good practice is to define the single executable (in this case dotnet) as entry point and then provide the rest as part of the CMD definition...

In your case you should try making these changes in your Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]

CMD ["app/myapp.dll"]
```

And also you might consider simply copying the app directory to /app and then you wouldn't need the app/myapp.ddl (as now you are changing WORKDIR to /app and then copying the app to app/ which in essence creates a /app/app folder)

I'd say your Dockerfile should look something like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2

COPY app/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/app /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]

CMD ["myapp.dll"]
```